# Возникает ошибка IndexError: list index out of range при правильно написанном коде

Tags: python, парсер

Не могу понять в чем проблема. В целом код написан верно и запускается иногда без ошибки. Может, что то не так в настройках. Использую программу atom на мак

```
def get_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    popular = soup.find_all('section')[1]
    plugins = popular.find_all('article')
```

```
def main():
    url = 'https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/'
    print(get_data(get_html(url)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
 line 48, in <module> main()<br>
  line 44, in main print(get_data(get_html(url)))<br>
   line 28, in get_data<br>
popular = soup.find_all('section')[1]<br>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Это значит, что на странице не нашлось элементов по селектору 'section'.

Comment: Не совсем так. Индексация в списках начинается с 0. Если был найден 1 элемент, то он будет по индексу `[0]`, а не `[1]`. Лучше всего, перед подобным вызовом элемента проверять длину списка: `len(soup.find_all('section')) > 0`